# AssetLibrary not return all assets with "ALAssetsGroupAll"

Tags: ios, ios7, alassetlibrary

I am querying the asset library with the following code

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [self defaultAssetsLibrary];
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    NSMutableArray *tmpAssets = [@[] mutableCopy];
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result)
        {
            [tmpAssets addObject:result];
        }
    }];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    finished([[tmpAssets sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]]  mutableCopy]);

} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    finished(@[]);
    NSLog(@"Error loading images %@", error);
}];
```

However it seems that I am not getting all of the assets, if I add images to the iPhone from an external source these are not showing in the list of assets received from the above code... I am getting what seems like everything else though. I suspected it could be a limitations of the framework but when I use instagram I noticed that the photos which were missing in my app were visible... How do i get every type of asset "ALAssetsGroupAll" not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not understanding how `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:` works. *It is asynchronous.*

To see what I mean by that, let me divide up your code using some numbers:

```
// (1)
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    // (2)
    if(result)
    {
        [tmpAssets addObject:result];
    }
}];
// (3)
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
finished([[tmpAssets sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]]  mutableCopy]);
```

The problem is that *3 executes before 2*. Thus there is nothing in `tmpAssets` yet.

So what are you supposed to do about this? Well, this method (and other ALAssets methods that work similarly) operate in a very strange and special way: they call their block *one extra time*, with a nil argument. (You seem to have realized this, since you are doing a nil test; but you have not understood what the implications are.) Your job is to test for a nil parameter. If the parameter is nil, *this is the final extra call*, and now you can do any cleanup. So, like this:

```
// (1)
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    // (2)
    if(result)
    {
        [tmpAssets addObject:result];
    }
    else
    // (3) // aha, finished, this is the extra time through
    {
        // NOW do something with tmpAssets!
    }
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to add all of the assets into a single array from all of the groups instead of for the groups individually with multiple calls to the finished block.

```
-(NSArray *)allAssets {
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    NSMutableArray *allAssets = [@[] mutableCopy];

    [[self defaultAssetsLibrary] enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if(result)
                [tmpAssets addObject:result];
        }];

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading images %@", error);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    return [tmpAssets sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
}
```